# PHP timezone conversion in seconds

Tags: php

The following code (I believe) should convert the given times between time zones however it doesnt. I've also tried converting it to a date() and that doesn't work either.

```
$send = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',1387470734);
$send->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('America/New_York'));
echo $send->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>'; // works
echo $send->format('U').'<br>'; // wont work    
echo '<br>';    
$newt = DateTime::createFromFormat('U',1387470734);
$newt->setTimeZone(new DateTimeZone('Europe/London'));      
echo $newt->format('Y-m-d H:i:s').'<br>'; // works
echo $newt->format('U').'<br>'; // wont work
```

Really not sure why this isn't working, so any help would be great. In effect I am expecting the U outputs to be different when compared even though they are given the same why are they not adjusted to the new timezone format. Thanks

A

Comment: Because `U` is __always__ GMT/UST so is an absolute value, irrespective of time zone

Comment: If you want a timezone equivalent of `U`; then take the `U` format value and adjust by the `Z` format value

Comment: Please look up how a UNIX timestamp is defined exactly. Hint: *"the number of seconds that have elapsed since 00:00:00 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC), Thursday, 1 January 1970, not counting leap seconds."*